# Smart battery protector

Tags: batteries, protection, smart

[image]

How does this smart battery protector work?

Answer (score 3):

Let's see how smart it is

1. R1 and VR1 form a voltage divider to report the battery voltage to IC1. This is built to conduct (some low current) if the voltage at pin 1 relative to pin 2 is at least 2.5 V. We want to disconnect the load at 10.8 V to protect the battery. So VR1 must be adjusted to deliver 2.5 V at a battery voltage of 10.8 V.
2. We start with a fully charged lead acid battery at 13.2 V and activate S1.  IC1 is conducting, but a saturaton voltage of about 2 V between pin 3 and pin 2 remains.
3. IC1 and ZD1 carry a heavy load until C1 is charged, critical for IC1.
   The voltage across the coil of the relay finally is 13.2V - 2V - 3.9V = 7.3V.
4. The developer assumes, that this is enough to activate the relay contact and enable the load. Possible for a 12 V relay.
5. The current trough the relay is 7.3 V / 200 ohm = 36.5 mA which is flowing all the time. This constantly wastes around 400 mW, summed up from IC1, ZD1 and the relay. A very smart circuit..
6. The battery finally reaches 10.8V and IC1 stops conducting, the relay turns off, C1 catches the back EMF of the relay and D1 feels a bit useless. The load is disconnected.
7. Since the battery has no load, the voltage recovers a bit, say up to 11.0V.
8. The voltage at pin 1 of IC 1 is again above 2.5, IC1 turns on again.
9. The voltage across the relay is now 11.0V - 2V - 3.9V = 5.1V. The developer hopes, that this is not enough to turn on the relay again. Sounds plausible.
10. The current through the relay is now 5.1V / 200 ohm = 25.5 mA, the circuit now wastes 0.28 W until the battery is down to 10.8 V again. An absolute smart circuit!
11. IC1 stops conducting and the remaining current flows via R1 and VR1. This is 10.8V / 24.7 kohm = 0.44 mA.
12. This remaining current is falling over (a long) time until the battery finally is absolute dead and unusable or someone recharges it.

At first attempt I didn't understand the purpose of D1. Now I've got it: If you accidentially connect the circuit with wrong polarity, it would survive for a minute or so until C1 explodes. But with D1 the circuit immediately dies with either burnt ZD1 or IC1 and another board is sold soon!

Comment: Isn't D1 a freewheeling diode for the relay? But than the question is what C1 is for... Filtering of fast transients?

Comment: @kruemi TL431 can amplify noise if it is close to the threshold. That may require C1. But if it is there, I think D1 is not needed. Slowing down a relay that much is not nice to the contacts.